# Ethereum as a private network is possible?

Tags: blockchain

can i deploy a private network like the way it does other private blockchains  with Ethereum ?
and the test networks in Ethereum only work for public right or can i deploy it there  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own private Ethereum if you want. Some test networks are private but you can make it local (essentially private).

Answer (score 1):

You can create it by hand by running `geth` or `parity` in a local network and manually configure nodes.

Or you can use services like Azure which creates "out-of-the-box" private Ethereum networks for you:

https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/ethereum-blockchain-as-a-service-now-on-azure/

Answer (score 0):

i'm working on a similar project https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network